# refer to gem's install folder

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I want to bundle ca certs with my gem to avoid ssh connection issues. How would I refer to my gem's install folder. In other words I want to do:

```
ENV['SSL_FILE'] = "#{install_dir}/ssl/cacert.pem"
```

How would I get install_dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gem.dir`

From the command-line, this command will print out the options for the environment on your computer:

```
$ gem environment
```

and this is the source code: [Gem::Commands::EnvironmentCommand](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems/commands/environment_command.rb) Check out the rest of the variables under the `#execute` method. If in case you need to use older rubies, `require rubygems` explicitly to get access to that command.